# Running multiple SELECT, INSERT INTO and DELETE

Tags: php, mysql

I am very very new to PHP. Please excuse all the errors. I am trying to create a submit verification for AJAX with the below listed PHP code to verify wether the variable `$_POST['genre']` exists in the database or not. if not , insert, if it does exist, then delete. However it seems like it is only inserting and not deleting. Any help would be great! 
Thank you,

```
<?php       
    include('../includes/includes_db_connect.php'); 
    $tbl_name       = "genres";
    $genre          = $_POST['genre'];
    $query          = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT types FROM genres WHERE types = '".$genre."'");
    $row            = mysqli_num_rows($query);

    if ($row > 0){
        echo "delete";
        mysqli_query($con, "DELETE FROM ".$tbl_name." WHERE types = '".$genre."'");     
    } else 
        echo "inserted";    
        mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO ".$tbl_name." (types) VALUES ('".$genre."')");              
    mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Print your first sql query and run it in your database to see if it returns a row or not

Comment: mysqli supports parametrized queries, you should not use concatenation to fill in user-supplied values, you're subject to SQL injection.

Comment: Does the `types` column contain just a single genre, or a list? Your query looks for an exact match, not a substring.

Comment: @Awlad Liton - tried your suggestion - but does the same thing.

Comment: @Barmar - it is a list of genres in "types".

Comment: can you show us the value of $_POST['genre'] in your question?

Comment: and your insertion query will be execute in every time since it is in the outside of your  if else statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing braces in else statement.

The correct way to use if else is

```
if {PUT ALL STATEMENT WHICH SHOULD BE EXECUTED IF CONDITION IS STATISFIED} 
else {PUT ALL STATEMENT WHICH SHOULD BE EXECUTED IF CONDITION IS NOT STATISFIED}
```

If you don't use {}, only one statement will be executed, which in your case echo "inserted", and insert query is outside else statement, hence it is getting executed all the time.

So even if it is deleting, same time it is inserting again, hence the behaviour.

Comment: To be more specific, he has correct braces around the `if` block, but not around the `else` block.

Comment: @ Sameer. You were right! Thank you so much. you made my day. And to everyone else: This is my first post and you guys are tops! thank you everyone for your input.